# React native blurRadius prop for Image is not working on local files on expo

Tags: react-native, expo

The blurRadius property for react native Image component is not working for local files, only remote URIs.

Is this a version problem? I'm using expo sdk 33.

```js
<Image
  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
  source={require('../../../assets/images/home.png')}
  blurRadius={1}
  resizeMode="contain"
/>
```

Found a similar question about that but it's not a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug in react-native. Try using import instead of requireAsset

`import image from '../../../assets/images/home.png'`

then render your component using the import

```
<Image
  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
  source={image}
  blurRadius={1}
  resizeMode="contain"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please increase the   `blurRadius` value (1 to 10)

```
 blurRadius={10}  <== Magic Code
```

Here This Docs[This](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#blurradius)